# What FHIR API would enable one to write notes to patient chart - specifically in Epic

Tags: hl7-fhir, dstu2-fhir

I'm looking for a way to write notes into patient chart in Epic. Couldn't find any current FHIR specs about writing notes , but I didn't find this proposal http://wiki.hl7.org/index.php?title=ClinicalNote_FHIR_Resource_Proposal

Are there any other options ?

Answer (score 4):

Great question. I work on the FHIR team at Epic and from a FHIR perspective we are having a similar problem identifying the appropriate place in FHIR to return notes. The proposal you have linked is a starting artifact in defining a new resource for that purpose. Until we determine in the FHIR community if a new spec should be created or an existing FHIR resource should be used, we do not have a FHIR specification to develop support against.

Outside of FHIR, today there are multiple ways to get notes into Epic such as HL7 v2, document based exchange, or something more Epic defined (these are just the ones I'm aware of). Without knowing more about your use case, it is hard to say what option may or may not meet your needs. I recommend you reach out through the contact us at https://open.epic.com/. From this email group they can dive into what integrations would meet your specific scenario and you will have input from a full gamut of integration experts.

And if you are interested in the standards side of things and getting notes in the FHIR specification, I'd encourage you to get involved on chat.fhir.org or any of the HL7 FHIR meetings to provide input on the specification!

*Edited to point to website instead of email.

Comment: Soliciting email to a random address is a bit suspicious. Perhaps you could link to a presentation of this mailing list or something instead, or as well?

Comment: Looks valid, but I think a link to here: https://open.epic.com/ would be much better

Comment: Thanks Danielle. That's helpful. Our use case for writing notes to patient chart is a small feature to improve on our bigger app. The app can fully function with or without the notes, and we are currently integrating via CCDs and Epic APIs ... adding HL7v2 ( + VPN ) into the mix for a small feature would be a huge overhead for little benefit. I didn't see any Epic web services APIs that would handle note writing either. It's too bad, because I know Notes are a big part  of a pharmacists (using Willow) workflow.